# How can I passed data from collection view cell to new view controller (programmatically and without storyboard)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I have problem about passing data from collection view cell to new view controller. I have collection view cells and each cell have image and labels and I want to create new view controllers for each cell.

I already tried to UINavigationController but present and navigationController codes not working under didSelectItemAt indexPath function. Everybody did this with storyboard but I didn't use it and I can't find solution.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("#\(indexPath.item)!")
    //let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! itemsCell
    //let cell = itemler[indexPath.row]

    let newView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: orderBasketController())
    self.present(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Code had a error which is *Value of type 'feedCell' has no member 'present'* .

Comment: Could you show a section of the code that you have tried? Is there any specific part that causes an error?

Comment: @MaartenDev I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject dependencies to view controller in `init` method.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let yourCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCellClass else {
            return
        }
        let yourModel = Model(title: yourCell.title, image: yourCell.image)
        let targetViewController = TargetViewController(model: yourModel)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(targetViewController, animated: true)
        // or if it's not in navigation controller
        // present(targetViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have an error which is 'Use of unresolved identifier 'present''.

Comment: Who is delegate for your `UICollectionView`?

Comment: `cv.delegate = self` is my delegate

Comment: What class is the delegate?

Comment: I had lots of search on internet and I need write a protocol I assume. Is this correct? And also can I write function and call that controller in that function is true?